# Not able to connect websocket to the server (https) on iOS app in both release and debug mode

Tags: websocket, react-native-ios

CONTEXT: 
I have developed a react-native app that uses websocket (using socket.io-client) to connect to https web server (nginx).

PROBLEM: I am not able to connect to the https webserver(nginx) using websocket on iOS app (real device) in both release and debug modes.

EXTRA INFORMATION:
The app is perfectly working on android.
Curiously, the app is working perfectly on iOS when I turn on "Debug JS remotely" from a real device.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was using version 2.0.0 of socket.io-client for my app.

It seems this version is trying to use browserwebsocket in all websocket communications.
When I run my app on release mode or on debug mode (without "Debug JS remotely" option enabled from the device) the app is trying to use the browserwebsocket to establish a connection which will not work on a react-native app.

When I enable "Debug js remotely" option on the device, the app will be able to use the chrome browser to establish a websocket connection using the browserwebsocket.

I downgraded the version of socket.io client to 1.5.1 and the app was able to establish websocket connection in all modes. This version has built-in support to deal with react-native app websocket communications.

There may be a way to make version 2.0.0 of socket.io to make it work for react-naitve apps.
If you have a way to make that work, please submit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you fixed your problem, but instead of downgrading did you go through the following steps? 
Because in iOS you need to add a key in `NSExceptionDomains` in info.plist. You had to go to your info.plist and right click on it then choose the `open as > source code` in your project and modified your code as bellow:

```
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://yourdomain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
</key>
```

Then clear and rebuild again.